# Remove the duplicate in modal and view

Tags: android

I am writing an app involve a class.

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private String sex;
    //other attributes
}
```

and need an Activity to show the User info.

```
class ShowActivity {

    public void onCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
    }
}
```

the activity_show layout like this

```
<LinearLayout>

    <Text
        android:id="@+id/tx_name"
    />

    <Text
        android:id="@+id/tx_school"
    />

    <Text
        android:id="@+id/tx_sex"
    />
```

I also have another activity to modify the user.

```
class EditActivity {

    public void onCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    }
}
```

and the layout file

```
<LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_school"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sex"
    />
```

You can see that. For every attribute of User, there are three places about it

```
1. one field of the User class
2. one view that have the meaningful id in activity_show layout
3. one view that have the meaningful id in activity_edit layout
```

If i want to modify the name of one field in User, for example

```
String name -> String nickname;
```

In order to keep consistent, I have to modify the id in layout

```
et_name -> et_nickname;
```

This is annoying. Everytime I change one place, I have to change another two place.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: You could generate your layouts dynamically, but it'd be more work than just changing two `View` IDs, which, btw, you don't really _have_ to change, since they don't affect how your app runs.

Comment: You don't have to change the layout if you change the Java object

Comment: @MikeM. how can I generate the layouts based on the java object dynamically, can you give more detail info? I think it's hard for me to do that.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that. But if I modify the java object, for example, change or add or remove field, I have to modify the layout file manully, can I do it in a auto way?

Comment: There is no way for a layout to know how you want to display your data, so no, there is no automatic way.

Comment: @cricket_007 fine, thank you anyway